# MutationObserver on iFrame javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, mutation-observers

I have an iframe containing a source `www.abc/main.html`

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="http://www.abc/main.html"></iframe>
```

abc/main.html imports and executes some js files.
I want to use a MutationObserver to get the name of the js files it is importing.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                [].filter.call(mutation.addedNodes, function (node) {
                    return node.nodeName == 'IFRAME';
                }).forEach(function (node) {
                    node.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                        console.log('loaded', node.src);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

This is what I am using. Referring: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884473/detect-load-of-iframe-not-same-domain-dynamically-added-in-javascript-or-jque)

But I am unable to get the name of the js file. Does it have to do with the CSP set on the source of the iframe?

Note: The iframe content is not of the same origin as the parent document.

Comment: If it's the same origin you can use a `DOMContentLoaded` event with a `postMessage` method and a receiving`message` event on the page containing the iframe. This makes it much simpler as you can simply pass over the script files with `window.parent.postMessage([...document.scripts].map(js => js.src), "*");`

Comment: It's not the same origin...

Answer (score 1):

MutationObserver only observes your own document.

Without explicit CORS support from the remote site, it is completely impossible to observe or interact with a frame from a different origin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way to control the js that is being imported by the iframe content? Without sandboxing it.

Comment: No. And AFAICT you wouldn't be able to *control* it via MutationObserver because scripts run automatically once they are inserted into DOM.

Comment: are there any other means by which one can control the scripts iframe imports? not using sandbox i.e